# Raster from XYZ csv format

Tags: python, gis, gdal, geopandas, rasterio

I have a large csv file of 3 columns of x y and z values. I want to do the following:
1. How to convert that csv into vector shape file (points).
2. How to convert the obtained points in step 2 into geo raster.
3. Lets say a set of separate point file in "shp" format how to extract the values from the raster obtained in step 2 into new the csv file so I can perform so statistics on it.

The issue is that I'm new to geo-processing using python, for example for step 2 I used to do that easily in R using "raster" package and for step 3 also using "extract" function in "raster" package. However, in python I can do step 2 in geopandas but step 2 and 3 no simple answer is available.

Comment: The normal procedure is converting directly XYZ to Raster. With GDAL tha's trivial.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254330/python-gdal-grid-correct-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact case exists in the GDAL [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html).

Assuming your data, `dem.csv`, is like:

```
Easting,Northing,Elevation
86943.4,891957,139.13
87124.3,892075,135.01
86962.4,892321,182.04
87077.6,891995,135.01
...
```

You create a [VRT](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) to describe it:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="dem">
        <SrcDataSource>dem.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Easting" y="Northing" z="Elevation"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Or, if the CSV lacks columns, you can specify your `GeometryField` like this:

```xml
<GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_1" y="field_2" z="field_3"/>
```

Save that as something like`dem.vrt` for use in later commands.

Then to interpolate with `gdal_grid` and produce a GeoTIFF output:

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0 -txe 85000 89000 -tye 894000 890000 -outsize 400 400 -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l dem dem.vrt dem.tiff
```

Comment: The issue here is 1.  the output is somehow vertically flipped ...2. using python API it produce 512kb Tiff and 3. How to modify the coordinates system for the faster and 4. How to speed the python gdal API because it's extremely slow compared to R

Comment: I'm not recommending the use of Python.

Comment: Then what language we use ?

Comment: It's possible to use the GDAL Python bindings as you have been; I just don't like them. The last block of code is simply the command line; the others are snippets of text files.

Comment: How about GMT how to use it to grid the csv file

Comment: I don't understand you. What is GMT?

Comment: Generic Mapped Tools

Comment: I've never used that, and it sounds like you're now asking a different question. I suggest you make a new question asking specifically about GMT if that's what you want to know. I answered with a GDAL answer because that's what you originally asked for.